# How to remove limit condition using CDbCriteria in Yii 1.1.14

Tags: php, yii, limit

I want to show full list of data from database using CDbCriteria and CActiveDataProvider.
I make like :

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->alias = 'C';
if ( !$enablePagination ) {
  $criteria->limit= 0;
  $criteria->offset= 0;
}
```

debugging CDbCriteria object I see :

```
$criteria::CDbCriteria Object
(
    [select] => *
    [distinct] => 
    [condition] => 
    [params] => Array
        (
        )

    [limit] => 0
    [offset] => 0
    [order] => name asc
    [group] => 
    [join] => 
    [having] => 
    [with] => 
    [alias] => C
    [together] => 
    [index] => 
    [scopes] => 
    [_e:CComponent:private] => 
    [_m:CComponent:private] => 
)
```

But tracing my sql I see anyway :

```
 SELECT *  FROM `tbl_category` `C` ORDER BY name asc LIMIT 10
```

How to remove limit condition ?

Yii 1.1.14.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$criteria->limit= -1;
```

If limit is less than 0, then it means there is no limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can't show full list of your data just using criteria. CActiveDataProvider automatically fetch the database based on `pageSize` option.

Set the `pageSize` option in `CActiveDataProvider` like this:

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('SomeModel', array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize' => SomeModel::model()->count(),
    ),          
));
```

Comment: Better set `'pagination'=>false` to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$provider = new CActiveDataProvider('ModelClass', [
    'pagination'    => false,
    'criteria'      => $criteria,
]);
```